# Format the XML String Generated using Oracle XMLAgg

Tags: xml, oracle

I am using the following query to generate an XML representation of the data. I expect the output to be idented like a regular XML format. Instead I receive a continuous string. I have tried appending CHr(13)||Chr(10) in my select statement but I don't get the correct output. Can someone provide insight on how the XML can be formatted? Thank you!

SQL Query:

```
SELECT
  XMLElement("Sample-Test" ,
      XMLAgg(
      XMLElement("Sample",
            XMLElement("SAMPLE_NUM", s.sample_number), 
            XMLElement("LABEL_ID", s.label_id),
            XMLElement("STATUS", s.status),
             (SELECT 
                XMLAgg( 
                XMLElement("Test-Details",
                    XMLElement("TEST_NUM", t.test_number),
                    XMLElement("ANALYSIS", t.analysis),                                                                   
                        (SELECT 
                         XMLAgg( 
                            XMLElement("Result-Details",
                            XMLElement("RESULT_NUM", R.RESULT_NUMBER),
                            XMLElement("RESULT_NAME", R.NAME))) 
                            FROM RESULT R WHERE t.test_number = R.test_number 
                            and t.SAMPLE_number = R.SAMPLE_NUMBER
                                                        )))                                                                            
               FROM TEST T WHERE t.SAMPLE_number = S.SAMPLE_NUMBER))) 
               ).getClobVal()  as XML                                             
 FROM sample s 
 WHERE s.sample_number = 720000020018;
```

Current Output: 
(CLOB) 720000020018720000020018C21ALT_S90_NONSPE_00121Alanine Aminotransferase22GLUCOSE_S90_NONSPE_00122Glucose

Expected Output:

```
<Sample-Test>
    <Sample>
    <SAMPLE_NUM>720000020018</SAMPLE_NUM>
    <LABEL_ID>720000020018</LABEL_ID>
    <STATUS>C</STATUS>
        <Test-Details>
            <TEST_NUM>21</TEST_NUM>
            <ANALYSIS>ALT_S90_NONSPE_001</ANALYSIS>
                <Result-Details>
                    <RESULT_NUM>21</RESULT_NUM>
                    <RESULT_NAME>Alanine Amino</RESULT_NAME>
                </Result-Details>
        </Test-Details>
    </Sample>
</Sample-Test>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `XMLSERIALIZE`:

```sql
SELECT
  XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT
    XMLElement("Sample-Test" ,
        XMLAgg(
        XMLElement("Sample",
              XMLElement("SAMPLE_NUM", s.sample_number), 
              XMLElement("LABEL_ID", s.label_id),
              XMLElement("STATUS", s.status),
               (SELECT 
                  XMLAgg( 
                  XMLElement("Test-Details",
                      XMLElement("TEST_NUM", t.test_number),
                      XMLElement("ANALYSIS", t.analysis),                                                                   
                          (SELECT 
                           XMLAgg( 
                              XMLElement("Result-Details",
                              XMLElement("RESULT_NUM", R.RESULT_NUMBER),
                              XMLElement("RESULT_NAME", R.NAME))) 
                              FROM RESULT R WHERE t.test_number = R.test_number 
                              and t.SAMPLE_number = R.SAMPLE_NUMBER
                                                          )))                                                                            
                 FROM TEST T WHERE t.SAMPLE_number = S.SAMPLE_NUMBER))) 
                 ) AS CLOB INDENT SIZE = 2) as XML                                             
 FROM sample s 
 WHERE s.sample_number = 720000020018;
```

**Edit**

It is not working for you, because, most probably, you are using Oracle 10g, and the `INDENT` option was introduced in version 11g. If this is the case, try below approach with the `EXTRACT('*')`:

```sql
SELECT
        XMLElement("Sample-Test" ,
            XMLAgg(
            XMLElement("Sample",
                  XMLElement("SAMPLE_NUM", s.sample_number), 
                  XMLElement("LABEL_ID", s.label_id),
                  XMLElement("STATUS", s.status),
                   (SELECT 
                      XMLAgg( 
                      XMLElement("Test-Details",
                          XMLElement("TEST_NUM", t.test_number),
                          XMLElement("ANALYSIS", t.analysis),                                                                   
                              (SELECT 
                               XMLAgg( 
                                  XMLElement("Result-Details",
                                  XMLElement("RESULT_NUM", R.RESULT_NUMBER),
                                  XMLElement("RESULT_NAME", R.NAME))) 
                                  FROM RESULT R WHERE t.test_number = R.test_number 
                                  and t.SAMPLE_number = R.SAMPLE_NUMBER
                                                              )))                                                                            
                     FROM TEST T WHERE t.SAMPLE_number = S.SAMPLE_NUMBER))) 
                     ).EXTRACT('*') as XML                                             
     FROM sample s 
     WHERE s.sample_number = 720000020018;
```

Comment: Thank you Przemyslaw. However I get an error "Missing Right Paranthesis" on the line where the INDENT is specified ) AS CLOB INDENT SIZE = 2) as XML . This error goes away if I remove the clause "INDENT SIZE = 2". On removing the clause the XML is no longer indented. What am I missing? Thank you so much for your help once again ...

Comment: @ERS Which version of Oracle are you using? Check my edited answer for probable solution for Oracle 10g (the use of `XMLSERIALIZE` is for 11g).

Comment: Thank you so much, I am using 10g - This works well!